# Windows: just do a division and get result

Tags: windows, batch-file, division

please I have

```
%V_Frame_Rate_cat% = 30000
%V_Frame_Rate_Denom% = 1001
```

simply I would like createa a new variable %division% that contains the result of 30000/10001 = 29,97002997002997

so `%division% = 29,97002997002997`

and another, called `%division2%  = 29.97002997002997` (difference is "." in place of ",")

and another, called `%division3% = 29.97`

How can I do? thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Answer**

If you want to put the results of the script into variables, you can do this:

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set count=1
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`cscript /nologo go.vbs 30000 1001`) DO (
  set var!count!=%%F
  set /a count=!count!+1
)
echo %var1%
echo %var2%
echo %var3%
endlocal
```

**Original Answer**

This might help.

```
Numerator = WScript.Arguments(0)
Denom = WScript.Arguments(1)
Result=Numerator/Denom                ' Simple floating point division
WScript.Echo Result
Result=Replace(Result,".",",")        ' Replace decimal point with comma
WScript.Echo Result
Result=Round(Numerator/Denom,2)       ' Round result to two decimal places
WScript.Echo Result
```

Save it as `go.vbs` then do

```
cscript /nologo go.vbs 30000 1001

29.97002997003
29,97002997003
29.97
```

Comment: Please help the site out by marking duplicates.